# How to wait until value is set to grab prop value

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I am trying to figure out this issue where .toUpperCase() in one of my components is giving an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toUpperCase')

I believe this is being caused because of a race condition in grabbing the prop in my reusable component called Icon as it happens about 50% of the time when I refresh the page.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './icons-svg-color.css';


const Icon = (props) => {
  const { icon, className } = props;

  return (
    <div className={`icon-32 ${className}`} style={{ backgroundImage: `url('data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32"><style>.text {font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 10px; fill:%23FFF;}</style><circle class="cls-1" cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="%231d5baa"/><text x="50%" y="63%" text-anchor="middle" class="text">${icon.toUpperCase()}</text></svg>')` }}>
      <div className={`icon-32  ${className}`} style={{ backgroundImage: `url(/static/images/assets/icons/svg/color/${icon}.svg)` }} />
    </div>
  );
};

Icon.defaultProps = {
  className: '',
};

Icon.propTypes = {
  icon: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  className: PropTypes.string
};

export default Icon;
```

Here is where it is being used:

```
  const renderMenuItems = () => {
    return chartMarkets.map((type) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem value={type} onClick={event => handleSelection(event)}>
          <Icon className={classes.menuItemImage} icon={type} />
          <Typography variant="body1">{type}</Typography>
        </MenuItem>
      );
    });
  };
```

I have tried stuff like defaulting it to empty string, but that is not the outcome I want as the app no longer crashes but the icon is not there. I also have tried conditional rendering where I pass in the value into the prop after the value is defined like so:

```
<MenuItem value={type} onClick={event => handleSelection(event)}>
   <Icon className={classes.menuItemImage} ***icon={type && type}*** />
   <Typography variant="body1">{type}</Typography>
</MenuItem>
```

But still has the same issue where it crashes the program with that same error. Also have tried using useEffect in the reusable Icon component like so:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    
  }, [icon]);
```

Is there any other solutions that I can try? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do simple like

```
return (
    icon && (<div className={`icon-32 ${className}`} style={{ backgroundImage: `url('data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32"><style>.text {font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 10px; fill:%23FFF;}</style><circle class="cls-1" cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="%231d5baa"/><text x="50%" y="63%" text-anchor="middle" class="text">${icon.toUpperCase()}</text></svg>')` }}>
      <div className={`icon-32  ${className}`} style={{ backgroundImage: `url(/static/images/assets/icons/svg/color/${icon}.svg)` }} />
    </div>)
  );
```

Comment: Hi Dennis, thanks for your response. I tried out your suggestion however, now I am just getting a blank screen

Comment: console says: Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

Comment: Hi Kimbo. Fixed. Sorry. Wrap your html into (). Try it now please.

Comment: Hey Denis, still the same result

Comment: Here's example https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-hooks-b2egio?file=/src/App.js